# Reference an Aliased Column in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to reference an aliased column in the sqlserver. here the 'dob' is the date of birth column from tbl_Student_Admission table

```
Select DATEPART(yy, dob) as years 
From dbo.tbl_Student_Admission 
Where years between '1990' and '1992'
```

Comment: `between '1990' and '1992'` !!! ...they are strings?! surely this should be `between 1990 and 1992`

Answer (score 3):

Just use a second SELECT:

```
select * from (
  select DATEPART(yy, dob) as years from dbo.tbl_Student_Admission
) v1
where years between '1990' and '1992'
```

Please note that by using a string for your BETWEEN, you're forcing the database to convert the results of DATEPART to a string, which will usually result in degraded performance. So you should use plain numbers instead:

```
select * from (
  select DATEPART(yy, dob) as years from dbo.tbl_Student_Admission
) v1
where years between 1990 and 1992
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a0ac/3)

Comment: `int` has higher datatype precedence than string so the conversion actually happens the other way round. If you care about performance none of the 7 answers supplied here should be used though. They are all unsargable. `SELECT DATEPART(yy, dob) AS years FROM   dbo.tbl_Student_Admission WHERE  dob >= '19900101' AND dob < '19930101'` is best.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it like this...

```
select * from (
select DATEPART(yy, dob) as years from dbo.tbl_Student_Admission 
) abc
where years between '1990' and '1992'
```

But this is not a good way... it will down your query performance. So you should use following query ..

```
select DATEPART(yy, dob) as years from dbo.tbl_Student_Admission where DATEPART(yy, dob) between '1990' and '1992'
```

Comment: Adding the derived table (the `abc` thing) won't change anything regarding the performance.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simpler way. so why should go complex ? You should try like this. This will work.

```
Select DATEPART(yy, dob) as 'years' 
From dbo.tbl_Student_Admission 
Where DATEPART(yy, dob) between '1990' and '1992'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first noticeable aspect of SQL that is different from other programming languages is the
order in which the code is processed. In most programming languages, the code is processed
in the order in which it is written. In SQL, the first clause that is processed is the

```
FROM clause,then Where -> Group By -> Having-> Select -> Order By
```

so the SELECT clause, which appears first, is processed almost last. So you cannot refer aliased column years from select list in where clause because it's not calculated yet.
You should write it as:

```
select [years] from (
select DATEPART(yy, dob) as years 
from dbo.tbl_Student_Admission 
) T
where T.years between 1990 and 1992
```

Comment: +1 for detailing the logical query processing phases

Answer (score 0):

A `CTE` is an alternative:

```
WITH myCTE 
    AS
    (
    SELECT  years = DATEPART(yy, dob)
    FROM    dbo.tbl_Student_Admission
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    myCTE
WHERE   years BETWEEN 1990 AND 1992
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `cross apply`

```
SELECT t.*, c.y
FROM dbo.tbl_Student_Admission t
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT DATEPART(yy, t.years) as y
) c
WHERE c.y between 1990 and 1994
```